# linux permission inheritance

Tags: linux, svn, permissions

I'd like some clarity on linux permission inheritance and subversion.
If I check something out that is owned by "svn:svn" and commit it, then, run svn update on a directory that was originally checked out, the file(s) gets MY permissions.  I am a member of group svn. Could I remove myself from the svn group to force the permissions to stay svn:svn when I do an update?
I am using an Subversion client to check out the files and this uses svn as the user.
Thanks

Comment: How are you using Subversion? For example, are you running svnserve or running everything through http? Or, are you using svn+ssh?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the sticky bit on the group permissions on that directory.

```
chmod g+S svndir
```

This will force the group permissions do be inherited by it's descendants.

Comment: +1: that's correct, but do note that this is something you do on the local machine, *not* something that has any effect on the repository. This must be done on the checkout machine whenever anyone checks out the module.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the group sticky bit on the parent directory, which'll auto-assign that directory to any *NEW* files created in there

```
chmod g+s .
```

I don't think it'll apply the sticky bit to any subdirectories, so you'd have to replicate this for each sub-dir, but at least the files will come out with the proper group ownership.

Answer (score 0):

Subversion doesn't store file ownership or permissions in the repository. If you check something out, it's owned by you. I'm not sure what it is you're trying to accomplish, but it's going to involve a script to change file ownerships on your local machine.

Comment: Ok Here is the delema I cant seam to get my head around. I am using a GUI (Sycro) to checkout and commit to a repo. I also have a hook that updates a webserver. If I check out a file, alter it and commit, the hook updates the server with the file and the correct (Svn) username.But...If I terminal into the webserver and do an update, the permissions are ME.How do I get around this? If I log into the webserver as "svn" it wont let me update.. tells me there is a permission problem.